# ERROR W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Estoy desarrollando una app móvil en la plataforma de android la cual debe de consumir webservices asmx, ya tengo implementada mi class a AsyncStack.. pero al correo mi app en mi emulador... me manda este erro en el android monitor

W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented....

> 04-13 20:20:12.700 1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo D/dalvikvm:
>   Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on) 04-13 20:20:12.740
>   1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find
>   class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;) 04-13
>   20:20:12.740 1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo I/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested 04-13
>   20:20:12.740 1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve interface method 18816:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested
>   (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z 04-13 20:20:12.740
>   1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 04-13 20:20:12.740
>   1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   04-13 20:20:12.740 1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18820:
>   Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode
>   (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode; 04-13
>   20:20:12.740 1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 04-13 20:20:12.780
>   1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
>   04-13 20:20:12.780 1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 416:
>   Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 04-13
>   20:20:12.780 1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 04-13 20:20:12.780
>   1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 04-13 20:20:12.780
>   1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 438: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType
>   (I)I 04-13 20:20:12.780 1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 04-13 20:20:12.910
>   1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo W/EGL_emulation:
>   eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 04-13 20:20:13.010
>   1634-1634/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug
>   mode 0 04-13 20:20:24.720 1634-2220/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo
>   D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 246K, 18% free 3224K/3924K, paused 6ms,
>   total 20ms 04-13 20:20:30.390 1634-2220/com.example.onc_lap.ejemplo
>   D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 400K, 21% free 3315K/4192K, paused
>   164ms, total 164ms

Aquí adjunto el código de mi activity:

```
package com.example.onc_lap.oncontrolmobile;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

String TAG = "Response";
EditText usuario;
EditText password;
private Button ingresar;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
//    public final int dialogo_alert = 0;
//    public String msje = "";
private String res = "";


public final int dialogo_alert = 0;
public String msje = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuario);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    ingresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ingresar);
    ingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String username = usuario.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            new webserv().execute();

        } //fin del click view

    });
}



class webserv extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    public String NAMESPACE = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/";
    public String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    public String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/Login";
    public String URL = "http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/ONControl_MobileWS.asmx";
    private SoapObject request;
    private HttpTransportSE transporte;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Login();
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPreExecute() {

       /* Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Principal.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesion ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(10);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();*/
    }




    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Principal.this.msje = res;
        // mostramos la respuesta en un toast
        Toast.makeText(Principal.this.getBaseContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (res.equals("Gracias por Iniciar Sesion")) {
            Principal.this.usuario.getText().toString();
            Principal.this.usuario.setText("");
            Principal.this.password.setText("");
            //envia al otro activity
            Intent intent = new Intent("menu.class");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "Tarea finalizada!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    public void Login() {
        URL = "http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/ONControl_MobileWS.asmx";
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        request.addProperty("usuario", Principal.this.usuario.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("password", Principal.this.password.getText().toString());

        try {
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive resultado_xml = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            res = resultado_xml.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

//run
```

}